# Linking many containers in Docker

Tags: docker, merge

Let's say I have a Java EE application which requires a database + I would also like to use apache.

Now, is it better to make a single image containing all three pieces or 3 containers for each of these and use the docker networking (linking is deprecated, right?) to connect them?

Comment: Multiple containers are better. Look at the concept of pods in Kubernetes that should give you a fair idea of how to structure things.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use built-in [Docker swarm mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/). This gives you built in encryption for passing your secrets around, such as the database login. Here's an [official Docker sample app](https://github.com/dockersamples/atsea-sample-shop-app) that shows how to do a Java Spring Boot app connecting to a database with each service separated.

Answer (score 1):

Docker is a lightweight solution for isolating applications. So if you have 3 different applications, you will almost always run those in 3 separate containers. Some of the advantages that gives you are:

- The ability to independently scale each component
- The ability to run components on different hosts
- The ability to independently upgrade one component without impacting the others

The only time I merge application components into a single container is when they cannot communicate through a networking API, and they really need filesystem- and process-level integration between the parts.